# how to resolve The data types nvarchar(max) and uniqueidentifier are incompatible in the add operator

Tags: sql-server-2016

how to resolve **The data types nvarchar(max) and uniqueidentifier are incompatible in the add operator.**

[image]

Comment: Please stop posting your questions as screenshots or images but as text. In that way we can copy and paste your code to try it ourselves.

Answer (score 4):

Change it to:

```
' + CAST(@formItemId AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '
```

Also, it's always a good idea to post your code rather than a screenshot as this makes it easier for everyone to assist you.

Comment: thank you Handy, i'm execute sp but getting error how to fix this kind of error: exec [usp_GetFormDatatest] '{25ACEF33-BFB9-4C19-8E0F-013CEE551651}                                                      Error Message: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 31
Incorrect syntax near 'ACEF33'.

Comment: You need to quote the uniqueidentifier. Try this - `''' + CAST(@formItemId AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '''`